# Connecting MySQL to a PC on LAN

Tags: mysql, jdbc, zend-studio

I am attempting to connect to my MySQL server through another PC instead of only using localhost. Both machines are on the same LAN, and pinging each other was successful. Would this really be as simple as changing:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/progdb";
```

to something with my IP address? For example:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://123.456.789.1/progdb";
```

or is there something more complicated neccessary here?

Comment: use ip address instead of localhost.

Comment: Consider firewalls and and license restrictions for the data access components if present (i.e. FireDac).

Comment: I guess you should change the tag from `zend-framework` to `zend-studio` because `zend-framework` has nothing common with `jdbc` usually